# Call external API and display JSON data using Node.JS

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I am trying to make a simple application using the [Challonge API](http://api.challonge.com/v1/documents/tournaments/index)

What I want to achieve, is to display all the tournaments I've created on Challonge on my personal page.

I've used request and I was able to fetch the tournaments data from my account in JSON format, however I don't know how can I display it in index.html.

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var path    = require("path");
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  request({
    uri: 'https://api.challonge.com/v1/tournaments.json',
    qs: {
      api_key: '<key_here>'
    }
  }).pipe(res);
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Server listening on port 3000');
});
```

This is the JSON data retrieved:

```
[
    {
        "tournament": {
            "id": 3117104,
            "name": "Test",
            "url": "39ikguh0",
            "description": "Testing",
            "tournament_type": "single elimination",
            "started_at": null,
            "completed_at": null,
            "require_score_agreement": false,
            "notify_users_when_matches_open": true,
            "created_at": "2017-01-10T01:26:36.602+03:00",
            "updated_at": "2017-01-10T01:26:36.602+03:00",
            "state": "pending",
            "open_signup": false,
            "notify_users_when_the_tournament_ends": true,
            "progress_meter": 0,
            "quick_advance": false,
            "hold_third_place_match": false,
            "pts_for_game_win": "0.0",
            "pts_for_game_tie": "0.0",
            "pts_for_match_win": "1.0",
            "pts_for_match_tie": "0.5",
            "pts_for_bye": "1.0",
            "swiss_rounds": 0,
            "private": false,
            "ranked_by": "match wins",
            "show_rounds": true,
            "hide_forum": false,
            "sequential_pairings": false,
            "accept_attachments": false,
            "rr_pts_for_game_win": "0.0",
            "rr_pts_for_game_tie": "0.0",
            "rr_pts_for_match_win": "1.0",
            "rr_pts_for_match_tie": "0.5",
            "created_by_api": false,
            "credit_capped": false,
            "category": null,
            "hide_seeds": false,
            "prediction_method": 0,
            "predictions_opened_at": null,
            "anonymous_voting": false,
            "max_predictions_per_user": 1,
            "signup_cap": null,
            "game_id": 194,
            "participants_count": 0,
            "group_stages_enabled": false,
            "allow_participant_match_reporting": true,
            "teams": false,
            "check_in_duration": 360,
            "start_at": "2017-01-12T01:26:00.000+03:00",
            "started_checking_in_at": null,
            "tie_breaks": [
                "match wins vs tied",
                "game wins",
                "points scored"
            ],
            "locked_at": null,
            "event_id": null,
            "public_predictions_before_start_time": false,
            "ranked": false,
            "grand_finals_modifier": null,
            "predict_the_losers_bracket": false,
            "description_source": "Testing",
            "subdomain": null,
            "full_challonge_url": "http://challonge.com/39ikguh0",
            "live_image_url": "http://challonge.com/39ikguh0.svg",
            "sign_up_url": null,
            "review_before_finalizing": true,
            "accepting_predictions": false,
            "participants_locked": false,
            "game_name": "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive",
            "participants_swappable": true,
            "team_convertable": false,
            "group_stages_were_started": false
        }
    },
    {
        "tournament": {
            "id": 3117146,
            "name": "name-alexnodeapitest",
            "url": "alexnodeapitest",
            "description": "",
            "tournament_type": "single elimination",
            "started_at": null,
            "completed_at": null,
            "require_score_agreement": false,
            "notify_users_when_matches_open": true,
            "created_at": "2017-01-10T01:49:51.205+03:00",
            "updated_at": "2017-01-10T01:49:51.205+03:00",
            "state": "pending",
            "open_signup": false,
            "notify_users_when_the_tournament_ends": true,
            "progress_meter": 0,
            "quick_advance": false,
            "hold_third_place_match": false,
            "pts_for_game_win": "0.0",
            "pts_for_game_tie": "0.0",
            "pts_for_match_win": "1.0",
            "pts_for_match_tie": "0.5",
            "pts_for_bye": "1.0",
            "swiss_rounds": 0,
            "private": false,
            "ranked_by": null,
            "show_rounds": false,
            "hide_forum": false,
            "sequential_pairings": false,
            "accept_attachments": false,
            "rr_pts_for_game_win": "0.0",
            "rr_pts_for_game_tie": "0.0",
            "rr_pts_for_match_win": "1.0",
            "rr_pts_for_match_tie": "0.5",
            "created_by_api": true,
            "credit_capped": false,
            "category": null,
            "hide_seeds": false,
            "prediction_method": 0,
            "predictions_opened_at": null,
            "anonymous_voting": false,
            "max_predictions_per_user": 1,
            "signup_cap": 8,
            "game_id": null,
            "participants_count": 0,
            "group_stages_enabled": false,
            "allow_participant_match_reporting": true,
            "teams": null,
            "check_in_duration": null,
            "start_at": null,
            "started_checking_in_at": null,
            "tie_breaks": null,
            "locked_at": null,
            "event_id": null,
            "public_predictions_before_start_time": null,
            "ranked": false,
            "grand_finals_modifier": null,
            "predict_the_losers_bracket": null,
            "description_source": "",
            "subdomain": null,
            "full_challonge_url": "http://challonge.com/alexnodeapitest",
            "live_image_url": "http://challonge.com/alexnodeapitest.svg",
            "sign_up_url": null,
            "review_before_finalizing": true,
            "accepting_predictions": false,
            "participants_locked": false,
            "game_name": null,
            "participants_swappable": true,
            "team_convertable": false,
            "group_stages_were_started": false
        }
    }
]
```

How can I display all the tournaments I create on Challonge within my Node.JS index.html page?

My index.pug template:

```
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    title Tournaments
  body
    h1 #{tournaments}
```

Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: You can use `pug` to render the data.

Comment: How do I use pug within my application?

Comment: Just run `npm install pug` and look at the documentation of express on how to connect a templating engine.

Answer (score 0):

Your object shape is not a good one. Here is how is should look like `[{tournament1}, {tournament2}` instead of doing another nesting like in your case. With this shape of object you can easily iterate on the collection (which is an array using) using: `tournaments.forEach(function(tournament){ /*do something with this tournament */ }`. You can then use a template engine like pug ( was called jade) and pass it the tournaments object, then loop in the view called index in my case. Read the docs on how to set up the templating engine in express.

```js
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var tournaments = request({
    uri: 'https://api.challonge.com/v1/tournaments.json',
    qs: {
      api_key: '<key_here>'
    }
  })
  
  res.render('index', {tournaments});
  next()
});
```

`

Comment: That object shape was retrieved from Challonge API. How can I display tournament.name within the tournaments variable you've created? I've updated my first post with my pug template, however I only see [object Object] instead of the tournament name. I've also tried to modify h1 #{tournaments} to h1 #{tournaments.tournament} or h1 #{tournaments.tournament.name} but it didn't worked.

Comment: Ok if it is not your api. First select all the tournament object by doing: `var tournaments = request( /* the api call */). ` Then we iterate over the object by doing: then iterate like this: `tournaments.forEach(function(tour){
  tour.tournament.name
});`

Comment: Using forEach, throws this error:
TypeError: tournaments.forEach is not a function

Comment: Your data is an array It should normaly work. Try also `tournaments.map()`. It iterates as forEach.